# funnel-shaped scatterplot - looking for similar statistical methods than correlation or regression

Tags: probability, correlation, scatterplot

I believe I am looking up wrong keyterms when searching for solutions, so i'd appreciate some help.

initial situation: I want to analyse if specific forest stands are more prone to deer damage using drone data. I have
a) field survey data: Severity of deer damage on a scale from 1 to 8 and
b) drone data: lots of different data about forest stand (tree height, canopy variability, etc.)

The drone data seems to be not correlating with deer damage (using e.g. Pearson or linear regression). I also realised that my data is not a normal distribution

Most of my data plotted as scatter plots look funnel shaped [image: scatter plot].

(In this case, x-Axis = Severity of deer damage, y-Axis is the standard deviation of canopy cover in a radius of 10 m.)

Basically when deer damage is low (0 to 2), the canopy deviation varys completely randomly on a scale from 0 to 20%. When the deer damage is a 6 or higher, the standard deviation is nearly always below 6.

Is there a statistical method similar to correlation or regression to deal with these funnel shaped scatter plots so I can find areas that are prone to damage?

As a beginner, I believe I am using wrong keywords when I'm searching for solutions!

Thank you!

Comment: IIUC, each point in your plot is one canopy standard deviation. So without deer damage, you can easily have the same standard deviation of canopy cover as with deer damage, correct?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure that is correct. 
Which makes it impossible to make precise distinction between "no damage" and "damage". 
However if the canopy standard deviation varies from 0 for "no damage" but only from 0 to 5 for "damage" (which is the case with several parameters) i'm wondering if i can select areas that are more prone to damage

Comment: Yes. If you are looking for damaged areas, you can almost exclude those areas with large canopy sd.

Comment: Your question is missing lots of relevant information, starting with: what's canopy standard deviation? how do you compute it? A pairs plot of all the data would show what data you have: [How to interpret pairs plot in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353229/how-to-interpret-pairs-plot-in-r), if you use R.